# Is it possible to reprocess a flask-request e.g. after handling an exception? If yes, how?

Tags: flask, error-handling, custom-error-handling

Assume we need to catch an OperationalError from SQLAlchemy, because the database had gone away and the session needs to be closed like this:

```
@APP.errorhandler(sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError)
def handle_operationalerror(error):
    SESSION.close_all()
    --> now reprocess the request
```

How can restart the processing of the request from scratch?

Redirecting via a 3xx to the same URL won't help since I'm dealing with an SPA that does not honor 3xx